# Return subdocument type from collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

(I'm completely new to mongodb)

Assuming a collection `Entities` as:

```
{
"_id":...,
"name":"Entity1",
"properties": {
    "property1":{
      "name:"name1",
      "value:"value1"    
    },
    {
    "property2":{
      "name:"name2",
      "value:"value2"    
    },
    {
    "property3":{
      "name:"name3",
      "value:"value3"    
    }
  }
},
{
"_id":...,
"name":"Entity2",
"properties": {
    "property1":{
      "name:"name1",
      "value:"value1"    
    },
    {
    "property2":{
      "name:"name2",
      "value:"value2"    
    },
    {
    "property3":{
      "name:"name3",
      "value:"value3"    
    }
  }
}
```

in C# model:

```
public class Entity {
  public ObjectId _id;
  public string Name;
  public Dictionary<string, Property> Properties;
}
```

I would like to use c# mongodb linq to return `property2` (of type `Property`) from `Entity1`.

I know how to query it in shell but my problem is that whatever way i try to query Entities collection in c# linq, it seems to always return Entity. Can't find a way that it returns subtype.

Is it possible to do?

PS.
just to emphasise its a return type problem and not query, i can repeat "property2" key inside the object for query purposes.

Comment: Something like `var result = collection.Find(x => x.Name == "Entity1").Project(p => p.Properties.Single(s => s.Key == "property2")).ToList();`

Comment: you almost nailed it! only thing to add was `...Single(s => s.Key == "property2").Value...` to return actual `Property` type instead of `KeyValuePair<string, Property>`. Please add it as answer so i can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below find query.

```
var result = collection.
  Find(x => x.Name == "Entity1").
  Project(p => p.Properties.Single(s => s.Key == "property2")).
  Single(s => s.Key == "property2").Value;
```

Comment: could you please just say, what actually goes over wite for this query? does all the filtering happens on MongoDB and only `Property2` is returned or se filtering happens within app also?

Comment: This is the query the driver issues. `"query" : {
        "find" : "collection_name",
        "filter" : {
                "Group" : "Entity1"
        },
        "projection" : {
                "features" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
        }
}`. So it looks like filtering occurs in app.

Comment: oh, how do you check actual queries produced by driver? do you monitor that somehow in shell?

Comment: yeah run `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` to log all queries & `db.system.profile.find().pretty();` to view queries